# Cannot install Ruby's sass gem

Tags: ruby, sass

I am trying to install ruby' gem sass. I have run Ruby installation first and:
gem install sass. But I am getting an error:

**C:\Windows\system32>gem install sass
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'sass' (>= 0) in any repositor**y

Any idea what that might be?

Thanks

```
Update.
The connad: gem sources --add https://rubygems.org/ fails:
C:\Windows\system32>gem sources --add https://rubygems.org/
Error fetching https://rubygems.org/:
Errno::ETIMEDOUT: A connection attempt failed because the connected party 
did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed 
because connected host has failed to respond. - connect(2) for "api.rubygems.org" 
port 443 (https://api.rubygems.org/specs.4.8.gz)
```

It must be proxy setting that we use to access Internet. Is it possible to make Ruby to honor these settings?

Update 2.

```
C:\Windows\system32>gem sources --add http://rubygems.org/
https://rubygems.org is recommended for security over http://rubygems.org/

Do you want to add this insecure source? [yn]  y
Error fetching http://rubygems.org/:
        Errno::ETIMEDOUT: A connection attempt failed because the connected part
y did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection fai
led because connected host has failed to respond. - connect(2) for "api.rubygems
.org" port 80 (http://api.rubygems.org/specs.4.8.gz)
```

Comment: Whats the result of `gem sources`

Comment: C:\Windows\system32>gem sources
*** CURRENT SOURCES ***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do

```
gem sources --add https://rubygems.org/
```

and try again

Comment: By the way can you access rubygems.org? `traceroute rubygems.org`

Comment: traceroute rubygems.org gives an error, traceroute is not a command.

Comment: `tracert rubygems.org`

Comment: Tracing route to rubygems.org [151.101.64.70]
over a maximum of 30 hops:

  1     *        *        *     Request timed out.